dynamic union with trino
lets say i have an iceberg catalog in trino with a schema a and 3 tables in this schema.
i know that i can use this query to retrieve the snapshot information of test_table0
SELECT * FROM "test_table0$snapshots"

is there a way to dynamically union all snapshot tables in the schema. so i want the same result as the following would give me but dynamically from a given schema
SELECT * FROM "test_table0$snapshots"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM "test_table1$snapshots"
....

is that possible using trino or is there an object in the information_schema that i could use
